# Broadcasting with AlarmManager to call activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to call a method in another activity with the use of Alarm manager
I use a broadcasting to call alarm manager
I want just call a activityAlarm without ui (just alarm method)
I dont want open ui,
What should I do?

```
public class ReciveData extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(G.context, ActivityAlarm.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(G.context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        G.alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, 3000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

and this :

```
public class ActivityAlarm extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        alarm();
    }

    public void alarm() {
        Log.i("LOGALARM", "Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: most likely this means your alarm method should be moved to separate class (maybe also made static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call it without UI you should use `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service`, not `Activity`:

Instead of this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(G.context, ActivityAlarm.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(G.context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

You should call this:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(G.context, YourReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(G.context, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

With this there will be no UI (because it won't start the activity), and you can put the `alarm` method to your `BroadcastReceiver`

More about the `BroadcastReceiver`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 1):

((ActivityAlarm ) getActivity()).alarm();

This should work for you.